# Why can you set attributes in Jython's Java classes?

Tags: python, attributes, jython, built-in

Why are Python built-in classes read-only, but it is legal to set attributes for imported Java classes in Jython?

For example:

```py
>>> from java.lang import String 
>>> String.myMethod = lambda x: str(x) + " world"
>>> String("hello").myMethod()
hello world
```

Whereas, on the other hand, the following raises an exception:

```py
>>> str.myMethod = lambda x: x + " world"
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't think this is an apples-to-apples comparison.  The Python built-ins are 'special'.  Java's `java.lang.String` is standard, but not built-in.  A more faithful comparison to `java.lang.String` would be something like Python's `collections.OrderedDict`, and you will see you can assign new attributes to `OrderedDict`.  Perhaps someone will explain what makes the Python built-ins, like `str` special.  Perhaps it's as simple as the implementation of `str` and friends interrupts attribute assignment via the standard means to raise `TypeError`.